# JavaScriptClass : Simple conditional (ternary) Operator returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have the following code, using a ternary operator to terun if  a value is true or false.

My expected result of would be    *pp is true*, however i get the result that it is false.

How can this be? This doesnt make sense for me.

```
const test = (x) => {
    (x === 1) ? true : false;
}


let pp = test(1); // SHOULD BE TRUE


if (pp) {console.log('pp is true')}
else {console.log('pp is false')}; // PRINTS FALSE, BUT SHOULD BE TRUE
```

Comment: Use an expression instead of a code block: `const test = (x) => (x === 1) ? true : false;`

Comment: Or even simpler: `const test = (x) => x === 1;`

Comment: yes, you are rigth. sorry it was a stupid mistake

Comment: For this simple true or false tasks you can use some "shortcut" i would say like this `return !!(x === 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `boolean`:

```js
const test = (x) => {
    return (x === 1) ? true : false;
}


let pp = test(1);


if (pp) {console.log('pp is true')}
else {console.log('pp is false')};
```

Answer (score 1):

with the brackets { } you need to add "return" in the body

```
const test = (x) => {
 return (x === 1) ? true : false;
}
```

or without brackets

```
const test = (x) =>  (x === 1) ? true : false;
```